# what does the error "Length of label is not same with #data" when I call lightgbm.train

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm pretty new the LightGBM, and when I try to apply lightgbm.train on my dataset, I got this error:

`LightGBMError: Length of label is not same with #data`

I'm not sure where I made a mistake. I tried

`model = lightgbm.train(params, train_data, valid_sets=test_data, early_stopping_rounds=150, verbose_eval=200)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the dimensions of your training examples and the respective list of labels do not match. In other words, if you have 10 training instances you need exactly 10 labels. (For a multi-label scenarios a better formulation would be to replace label by labelling, or refer to the size of the array.)

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue , inspite of the fact that the shape of train_x and train_y is same. (75
00,35) , ( 7500,)

Comment: Did you find any reason for this ?

Comment: Did you find a reason?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the number of labels (`y.shape[-1]`) you're passing to the model is not the same as the number of features (`x.shape[-1]`) being passed. In my case, this was because I accidentally mixed up my train and test sets for `y`:

```
kf = KFold(5)
lgbm = LGBMRegressor()

for train,test in kf.split(X):
    lgbm.fit(
        X.iloc[train],
        y.iloc[test], # should be 'train', not 'test'
    )
    # ...
```